# Forward declaration of std::hash<MyClass>

Tags: c++, hash

I have multiple classes which overloads std::hash operator(). Let's say:

A.h

```
class A
{
...
}

namespace std
{
  template<typename T>
  struct hash;
}

A.cpp

template<> struct std::hash<A>
{
  public:
  virtual std::size_t operator()(const A& joint) const noexcept
  {
..

}
```

And similar classes let's say `class B` and `class C`

Now `class B` uses A's hash like:

`boost::hash_combine(h, std::hash<A>{}(b.getA())`

Problem: 
`error: use of deleted function std::hash<A>::hash()`

I tried:
A.h

```
namespace std
{
  template<typename T>
  struct hash;
}
```

B.h

```
class B 
{
   friend struct std::hash<A>;
}
```

Comment: Do you really have `template<> struct std::hash<A>` in `A.cpp`?

Comment: @tadman specializing `std::hash` is 100% allowed and is idiomatic if you want  your object to be useable in the unordered associative containers.

Comment: Most likely this is a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes I have defined `std::hash` in A.cpp like I said.

Comment: @NathanOliver the pointer you pointed, does it mean I have to write ALL the definitions of std::hash<> .. for all of my class in one cpp file? I have more than `class C` which depends upon `A` and `B` .

Comment: No, put each specialization in each classes header file.  Template code for the most part needs to live in header files for the compiler to be able to do its thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver Correct, that's exactly where I'm not sure. How to just declare the std::hash<A> ?

Comment: Move the `template<> struct std::hash<A> ...` from A.cpp to A.h

Comment: Oh you mean the whole definition I should move to header file? Well then the problem is `B` is using `A`. `C` is using `A` and `B`. I can't really put the definition in headerfile

Comment: @NathanOliver: The `std::hash<A>` isn't actually template code though. It doesn't need to be in a header.

Comment: @MooingDuck You still have to have it declared in the header file, otherwise dependent code doesn't know there is a specialization and will use the default template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the `std::hash<A>` specialization in `A.h`, so that `B` and `C` will be able to see that the specialization exists and that it has an `operator()` member.

If `B` and `C` can't "see" the `std::hash<A>` specialization, then they will instantiate the primary `std::hash` template, which is disabled because the standard library doesn't know how to hash your user-defined type `A`.

If you declare the `std::hash<A>` specialization in `A.h`, but you do not define it, then `B` and `C` will see it as an incomplete class, which means the `operator()` cannot be called.

So you must define `std::hash<A>` in `A.h`. You can do so like this:

```
// A.h
namespace std {
template <> struct hash<A> {
    std::size_t operator()(const A&) const noexcept { ... }
};
}
```

You could also move the definition of `operator()` to the `A.cpp` file:

```
// A.h
namespace std {
template <> struct hash<A> {
    std::size_t operator()(const A&) const noexcept;
};
}

// A.cpp
namespace std {
std::size_t hash<A>::operator()(const A&) const noexcept { ... }
}
```

Comment: I tried to just define those function, but had no success. I edited the question to show how I am defining right now

Comment: @codemuncher As I said, a definition of the `std::hash<A>` specialization needs to be placed **in the header file**, that is, `A.h`.

Comment: Yes agreed. Could you please update answer on how to correctly declare the `std::hash<A>`? I tried multiple ways and I get  1) duplicate definition. 2) The way I defined right now is given in question.

Comment: @codemuncher: The key insight is to separate the concepts of the declaration of `std::hash<A>`, the defintion of `std::hash<A>`, the declaration of `std::hash<A>::operator()`, and the definition of `std::hash<A>::operator()`. All declarations should be in headers.

Comment: @Brian Looks like I had my Cpp 101 lessons forgotten! I had declared it fine but when I was defining I was redefining the struct. Shit! THANK YOU!